# Why is there a homogenous least square problem when the solution is always $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let's say $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and let's consider first that $A$ is of full rank that is the rank of $A$ is $r=\min(m,n)$

The goal is to solve the least square problem $Ax=0$

Define the error $E(x)=\|Ax\|_{2}^{2}$.

Since $A$ is of full rank, why can't we just say that $x=0$ is the solution to this homogenous least square problem? why is this not preferred over the usual solution to this problem that is the eigenvector corresponding the smallest eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$?

Alternatively, if $r<\min(m,n)$ then we may have infinite solution or no solution right?

Comment: Yes, $x=0$ is the solution to your homogenous least square problem, and that is why we call it the trivial solution. However, you need to learn what if the solution is nontrivial and has some constraints like $\|x\|=1$. If the world is that simple, lots of theories are unnecessary.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, it is the constraint on $x$ that we need to satisfy @Tab1e